# Resize an Icon in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, svg, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack

I'm attempting to render an SVG icon that is stored on the device, which I have successfully accomplished. However, I'm encountering a problem with resizing the icon, and the .size() modifier doesn't seem to work. Here's a screenshot showing the issue when I use the size() modifier. Additionally, I've added a red border to make the boundaries of the icon space more visible.

[image: Icon with .size() modifier]

Also here is a screenshot of the icon without the `size()` modifier:

[image: Without modifier]

And here is the code snippet:

```
badge.iconImage?.localFilename?.also { iconUrl ->
                if (iconUrl.endsWith("svg")) {

                    FileInputStream(AppUtils.getFilesBaseDir() + iconUrl).use { stream ->
                        val painter: Drawable = PictureDrawable(
                            SVG.getFromInputStream(stream, null).renderToPicture()
                        )
                        Column {
                            Icon(
                                painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(painter),
                                contentDescription = null,
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .padding(6.dp, 2.dp, 0.dp, 2.dp)
                                    .border(1.dp, Color.Red)
                            )

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

So it seems that the icon gets cut off when the `.size()` modifier is applied. Also what I tried is to wrap it with the `Box()` compose element and defining the height and witdth, but with no success. Any other ideas how to resize the icon?

Comment: Can you please add a sample image to show what should be the expected output and what you're getting right now?

Comment: I think I already described in the question what Im trying to accomplish. The expected output would be, the icon with the same size as the text for example.

Comment: You are not supposed to use svg like this. you can convert svg into vector drawable and then you will be play around size of it. and this is a good way what I'm using in my project

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the svg itself. Can you add the svg code to your question?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The same SVG icon is used in other places of the app in combination with xml layouts and works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Composable
private fun Demo() {
    val localDensity = LocalDensity.current
    var textHeightDp by remember { mutableStateOf(0.dp) }

    Row(modifier = Modifier.background(Color.White)) {
        Icon(
            painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_bell_bolt),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(textHeightDp) // Set height same as the text
                .wrapContentWidth()
                .border(1.dp, Color.Red)
        )
        Text(modifier = Modifier.onGloballyPositioned {
            // Get the height of the Text in Dp
            textHeightDp = with(localDensity) { it.size.height.toDp() }
        }, text = "ANDROID")
    }
}
```

Here is the output of this function.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not much helpful as I'm not using a vector drawable.

Answer (score 0):

I turns out that the svg file had a larger viewbox than the actual viewport of the icon. So the solution was to resize the view box using the AndroidSVG library (which is already used in my project) by calling the following method:

`svg.setDocumentViewBox(0f, 0f, 150f, 150f)`.

So in my case it was requred to resize the viewbox and this is how I did it:

```
badge.iconImage?.localFilename?.also { iconUrl ->
                if (iconUrl.endsWith("svg")) {
                    FileInputStream(AppUtils.getFilesBaseDir() + iconUrl).use { stream ->
                        val svg = SVG.getFromInputStream(stream, null)
                        svg.setDocumentViewBox(0f, 0f, 150f, 150f) // this part was missing
                        val painter: Drawable = PictureDrawable(svg.renderToPicture()) // after resizing the viewbox, render the svg to a picture

                        Column(
                            modifier = Modifier.border(1.dp, Color.Red),
                            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
                        ) {
                            Icon(
                                painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(painter),
                                contentDescription = null,
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .size(32.dp)
                            )
                        }
                    }


                }
            }
```

This was mentioned in [the AndroidSVG documentation](https://bigbadaboom.github.io/androidsvg/faq.html#My_SVG_won%27t_scale_to_fit_the_canvas_or_my_ImageView)